# Send Prometheus metrics from external cluster to Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch, digital-ocean

I currently have a Kubernetes cluster up and running in Digitalocean.

In order to monitor it, I use Prometheus and the Grafana Cloud which works nicely.

However, I wonder whether it is possible to send the Prometheus metrics to AWS Cloudwatch instead.

Many thanks for your input.

Comment: IIRC, Cloudwatch can digest prometheus metrics. Then you could utilize Prometheus' [federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/).

Comment: @markalex Many thanks for your input. Could you explain in a little more detail to me how I can make that happen? I am not very experienced in that.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus server exposes all it's current metrics through endpoint `/federate`. You can see an example [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/federate?match%5B%5D=%7B__name__=%7E%22n.*%22%7D): this page shows all current (non-stale) metrics with the name that starts with `n`.

This way you can configure [federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/) between multiple Prometheus servers (for example to avoid scraping same server multiple times, or to introduce some redundancy).

Then you [can configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights-Prometheus-Setup-configure.html) CloudWatch to scrape Prometheus metrics from your current Prometheus server. Once you'll configure this (with `match[]` `{__name__=~".+"}` for example), your CloudWatch should start scraping data from Prometheus itself, and data on both servers should be almost the same (except that on CloudWatch timestamp will be a tad too late, since timestamps are not transferred with federation);

Comment: @marklatex Many thanks again. Is it possible to encrypt the communication, such that metrics are not public, but can be scraped?

Comment: @tobias, I believe you can both encrypt and add authentication for this. Read more [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/https/) about current prometheus configuration, and [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#tls_config) and [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config) (`basic_auth:` block) for scraping configuration.